# Where can I find my crash logs?

Tags: macos, mac, logs

Console prints:

> default  17:16:18.554342 -0700   ReportCrash Saved crash report for APP_NAME[50432] version 1.2.3 (4) to APP_NAME_2020-03-17-171618_MacBook-Pro.crash

I would like to ask you, where could I find my crash logs?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Open the `Console` app from the `Application` -> `Utilities`, you will see the log files.

Comment: In Console, you will see directories that @TJ Luoma mentions too, but it may not list all the files in the UI. I'd recommend using Reveal in Finder right-click option once you locate the right folder from the console.

Comment: I found that System Reports in Console worked for a macOS crash (kernel panic) - scroll down to the `Kernel_*.panic` log files.

Answer (score 36):

Console app has them neatly arranged depending on if a system level process has crashed or a user level process...

[image]

From there you can see if it's in ~/Library/Logs or /Library/Logs - you will get crashes and panics and hangs in separate files. Don't forget to look in /private/var/log as well.

Answer (score 27):

~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ (where ~ refers to your Home directory).

~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice are the crashlogs for your iOS devices (if any).

~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter also has links to items in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/

Answer (score 14):

To find the crash files, you can run *Console* app which will display all the system messages. If any specific application crashed, look in *User Reports*. If it's system crash, check in *System Reports*. Once you have found the crash file, you can *Reveal in Finder* (usually located in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`).

If the crash resulted in reboot, in *All Messages* look line stating its *Shutdown Cause* and check the following [list of Shutdown Causes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/22781) for further information.

Alternatively you can also check the log files in `/var/log` (such as `system.log`), or in real-time by `log stream`.

You can also check where dumps are generated by monitoring `system.log` file, e.g.

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep crash # Hit Control-C to stop.
```

To scan for the previous crash files, run:

```
grep crash /var/log/system.log
```

To generate the actual core dump files (in `/cores`), see: [How to generate core dumps in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412156/55075)

---

To make sure your macOS is healthy, perform the following tests:

- Use [coconutBattery](http://coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) app to check your current battery health.
- Run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).

---

If your system reboots often, you can also try to:

- Make sure you didn't modify your `boot-args` (check by `nvram boot-args`).
- [Reset the System Management Controller (SMC)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).
- [Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Comment: Helluva an answer right there ☝️