# How do you get system diagnostic files from macOS?

Tags: macos, error

I am trying to debug a crashed (or hanging) app. How do I get the diagnostic files from the crash?

Answer (score 25):

Individual crash reports are stored in /Library/Logs/CrashReporter but there is a system wide log collection tool called [sysdiagnose](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html).

Once you start experiencing the issue, hold down the
4 modifier keys and then press the period "." key. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

You should see the screen flash white. After about 15 seconds, a Finder window will open with a sysdiagnose file highlighted.

[image: Once you start experiencing the issue, hold down the "shift"+"control"+"option"+"command" keys and then press the period "." key.]

This keyboard shortcut simply executes the `sysdiagnose` command, so if you are familiar with Terminal and want to pass in a process ID, you can get enhanced debugging information about that specific program. The key shortcut calls the tool with no arguments and captures the basic report only.

Comment: is there a way, to get this by command line?

Comment: `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter` does not contain `.crash` files. Instead: `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`

Comment: The key chord for sysdiagnose will work only if the stackshot daemon runs. In [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87982/8546), the `launchctl` command will start the daemon.

Comment: is the `sysdiagnose` command also available in OS 10.6? I don't find a man page and `which sysdiagnose` returns nothing in OS 10.6.8, or do I have to install it explicitely?

Comment: @Martin my answer is edited to address your question.

Comment: The response to @Martin indicated an edited answer, but what I find is the phrase (on 10.8 or lower), and I can't find 'sysdiagnose' on 10.6 either.

Comment: → Martin: if you still have a 10.6 (I don't), could you please open a `Terminal` or `xterm` and enter the following commands:
`type sysdiagnose ;
ls -al /usr/bin/sysdiagnose`, to test for its availability.

Comment: I landed on this page looking for why those modifier keys and a period "." was causing my screen to flash white quickly. I wasn't aware of this diag keyboard shortcut but knew something was happening. Unsure if this "white flash" happens on other macOS versions, but it's happening on Catalina 10.15.4. At first I thought it was taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 22):

## Apple sysdiagnose

This shell script(on 10.8 and lower) and executable program by the same name on 10.9:

- gathers system-wide diagnostic information
- is integral to OS X Lion and greater
- is not available as a separate download
- is not open source (I have asked Apple to make it so).

### Preparing for the keyboard-only approach to sysdiagnose

In Terminal, run the following command.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.stackshot.plist
```

- if prompted for a password, enter your admin password for the operating system
- that's a one-off, no need to repeat the command.

Take a written note of the following key chord, you'll need it later:

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

### Diagnosis by the system

When an issue occurs:

1. use the key chord
2. for at least ten seconds, touch nothing
3. allow maybe five or ten minutes for all parts of the `sysdiagnose` routine to complete – simply wait as long as you can (there'll be no on-screen indication of progress)
4. Finder should open a window to the end result.

#### Exceptionally

In rare cases, an issue may prevent sysdiagnose from completing (I have made improvement suggestions to Apple). If this happens – if you're sure that you have waited long enough – it may be sensible to restart the Mac. Then:

1. in Finder, go to `/private/var/tmp`
2. seek a file or folder with a name beginning *sysdiagnose_*
3. if that file or folder exists, move it to a convenient place – your desktop, maybe.

#### Hints

Without the key chord, you can run sysdiagnose from the command line (see below, Apple manual page). But it's often more useful, or necessary, to use the chord – so be prepared.

Whilst I don't encourage carelessness, you can be a little careless with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> … if you struggle to avoid the <kbd>fn</kbd> key on your laptop, don't worry; including it by accident should not prevent the run of `sysdiagnose`.

---

### Human analysis of diagnosis by the system

Hint: someone might like to ask a separate question about analysing the results of `sysdiagnose` – a more generalised answer could be useful.

#### If sysdiagnose_… from the `/tmp` area is a file

Presence of a `sysdiagnose_….tar.gz` file indicates that all parts of the `sysdiagnose` routine completed, and that the results were archived. If you wish, open the archive – its contents will appear as a folder.

#### If sysdiagnose_… from the `/tmp` area is a folder

Presence of a `sysdiagnose_…` folder (not a `.tar.gz` file) indicates that either:

- the routine was interrupted before completion; or
- some part of the routine could not complete.

#### Within the archive/folder

Some files are human-readable and may help to troubleshoot an issue.

Other files are more developer-oriented.

Related:

- [How does 'stuck' (in results of 'top') relate to 'not responding' (in Activity Monitor), 'spin' or 'hang'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58697/8546)

For an **incomplete** run of `sysdiagnose` it may be useful to focus some attention on files that are **abnormally** empty …

---

### Technical and other notes

[stackshot(1) OS X Manual Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923125121/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/stackshot.1.html)

[sysdiagnose(1) OS X Manual Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923121728/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html)

Some of what's above is a more generic edition of [an accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58595/8546) that appears elsewhere.

---

## Diagnostic and usage information, other files of interest

Be guided by the log list in Console:

[image: A screenshot of the sidebar of Console]

Expect to find files at the following paths:

- ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
- /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
- ~/Library/Logs
- /Library/Logs
- /private/var/log

Comment: → Graham: this is a + day: something to learn!
I think this kind of tool would benefit all sysadmins input if it was open source.

Comment: Hi, any idea on how that key chord can be turned off?

Comment: @StevieD probably unload the stackshot daemon. That is, if there's still anything like this in macOS.

Answer (score 4):

#### `Console`

To find existing diagnostic or crash files, open *Console* app and find the files in *User Reports* (located at `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`) in or *System Reports* (located at `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`) sections. See: [Where can I find my crash logs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26480/22781)

#### `sysdiagnose`

As per [official `sysdiagnose` instructions](https://download.developer.apple.com/OS_X/OS_X_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf) for macOS, you can trigger  a `sysdiagnose` either by:

<sup>Note: To access above link, you need to log-in to [Developer Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/) first.</sup>

- Briefly press the  following keys simultaneously:

  <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Period (.)</kbd>

  and wait. The `sysdiagnose` process can take 10 minutes to complete. Once finished, *Finder* should automatically appear showing the generated file in `/private/var/tmp/` (e.g. `sysdiagnose_2017.mm.dd_hh-mm-ss-0000_12345.tar.gz`).
- Trigger a `sysdiagnose` from Terminal by entering this command:

  ```
  sudo sysdiagnose
  ```

#### core dumps

To generate crash core dumps, see: [How to generate core dumps on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412156/55075)

Comment: How the hell do you disable this crap. Just something that flashes on the screen. Its been years and I've been trying to figure out what the hell happens. Can only be triggered like 3 times in a row ... then the shortcut no longer works for a while. Difficult to figure out like this. Years in the making.