# Mac Yosemite : disk size doesn't match its content size sum

Tags: macos, mac, storage

I want to clean up my disk storage (451,25 Go) but I don't understand why it doesn't match its content size (194,09 + 26,72 + ...), any idea?

It seems that a lot those mistery files are in 'Others' but can't find where.

Is there any hidden folders not listed on the screenshot below?

EDIT : The difference is Huge, more than 100Go, is there a way to remove some these files?

EDIT 2 : Since my post is unclear, try to say it better : Where are those missing files on the list and can I secure delete them? I already used CleanMyMac and made a Spotlight reindex.

[image]

EDIT 3 : Thanks kevin9794 now i know : It's System/Librairy/Cache/com.apple.coresymbolicationd  with 196.1Go!
Got a big list of "grow.xxxx" files. Looks like i can delete them [what is com.apple.coresymbolicationd in caches?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83978/what-is-com-apple-coresymbolicationd-in-caches). What's your opinion?

[image]

Comment: Finder sizes don't calculate any hard links, so will often over-estimate.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? Do you want to know what you can safely delete, do you want to know what Others is, do you know where the difference in reported sizes comes from, or something altogether?

Comment: ^^ I think it's the second do last, he's asking if there are any hidden folders not listed on the screenshot, so like, where he's space is going to if it's not any of the things he sees there.

Comment: While we wait for the answer to be taken off-hold, run an admin scan using the trial version of https://daisydiskapp.com (you will have to hit the triangle besides the "scan" button). Does it show any suspiciously big files / folders? At the bottom of the file/folder list there should be an entry for "(hidden space)". What does that say?

Comment: A 4.5 GB `lost+found` folder does not look like a good sign. I wonder if corruption of the disk directory might be responsible for some of the discrepancy. `du -h` (in sudo mode) in a Terminal window is usually a better tool for examining disk usage than the Finder, as I'm not sure the Finder can accurately size folders you don't have access permissions to.

Comment: It would be best to put the answer as an answer - then follow by the path used to get to the answer. At that point the question should be edited to remove all the edits and state the initial problem clearly. Anyone want to volunteer to start an answer? Ping me for cleanup as needed.

Answer (score 1):

- run an admin scan using the trial version of daisydiskapp.com
- the discrepancy was coming from System/Librairy/Cache/com.apple.coresymbolicationd
- open Onyx : http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html and do the cleaning
- restart