# Is there a user-friendly app that can create an archive of system.log files and the like?

Tags: macos, applications, script, logs

### Background

I have this command to create a **temporary** collection of selected log files –

`sudo tar -czf $TMPDIR/archive\ of\ install.log\ and\ system.log\ files\ only.tgz --options='compression-level=9' /private/var/log/*install* /private/var/log/*system* && sudo chmod 666 $TMPDIR/archive\ of\ install.log\ and\ system.log\ files\ only.tgz && open $TMPDIR`

– but it's usable only if the user at the command line is an administrator.

A [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) view of an archive produced by that command:

[image]

## Question

For OS X, is there a user-friendly third party app that can create an archive of a comparable collection of log files?

The ideal app:

- should work for normal users (and if so, **must** prompt for administrator credentials, which will be required to access some of the data)
- may be relatively system-agnostic (not limited to Mountain Lion).

---

### Approaches that I have ruled out

#### Console

It's great for many things, but not for collecting and archiving in the way outlined above.

#### Finder

It's user friendly but I'd prefer something that can perform the collection in a single step, or two – without browsing to the source directory. Moreover:

- a normal user can not use Finder to compress the required files.

#### [Apple sysdiagnose](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87982/8546)

It's powerful and fairly comprehensive, but can be unexpectedly time-consuming.

Only the most recent `system.log` file is archived.

Comment: The permissions on the install system logs are such that they are only readable by Administrators so all access will need to be authenticated

Comment: To clarify: the app will be for an administrative user who may be **sometimes logged in as a normal user**. They'll be prepared to enter credentials, but probably not prepared to log out (or fast user switch). Imagine, if you like, a need to collect log files **quickly** and with minimal disruption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use an AppleScript like this?

`do shell script "tar --disable-copyfile -cf ${TMPDIR}logs.tar /var/log/{system,install}.log*" with administrator privileges`

It requires entering the username and password of an admin user though.

Comment: Perfect – it'll be user-friendly, and it matches both ideals. I imagined AppleScript being used but my knowledge was rusty. I might add another answer for the "and the like" part of the subject line but this **is** the accepted answer.

Comment: Whilst options such as `--disable-copyfile` are not documented by Apple (in its [tar(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html)) the option is explained [in Super User](http://superuser.com/a/145833/84988).

Comment: Note to self, towards making visible the end result in Finder:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13820485/38108

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a ridiculous answer, but I've been toying with the free tier of [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) for this purpose.

It's actually a fairly heavy (in feature) web front end and a hadoop back end database to collect all log messages and make them searchable, indexable and actionable.

I wouldn't call it user-friendly per-se to set up, but the web interface isn't bad. But if you can install it and get it running, you probably have the tools to roll your own archive solution using terminal commands.

Comment: It's not ridiculous to make me aware :-) – thanks – but the [requirement to sign up](https://www.splunk.com/page/sign_up/download) will probably be unpalatable to the end users …

Comment: The software is licensed and requires you to register, but other than your time and email address, I've found them to honor requests to not email you unless you opt in to mailings from the company. For most use cases, the software is routinely free if you request a license after evaluating it.