# OS X Yosemite Crashing Frequently (Safari?)

Tags: macos, safari, crash, performance

I've got the problem that my Systems is often freezing and than shutting down or restarting. I have a Mid-2012 Macbook Pro Retina and before Yosemite I've never had such problems.

Just while writing this post my system froze again, this time with a crash report after rebooting.

Crash 1: 14:17 (time displayed when frozen)

```
14.05.15 14:15:12,596 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:12.596 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:13,857 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,858 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,858 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,858 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,859 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,859 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,860 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,860 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,860 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,861 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,861 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,861 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,862 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,862 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,863 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,863 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:13,863 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:20,978 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:20.978 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:27,979 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:29,089 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:29.089 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:31,689 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:31.688 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:39,096 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:15:41,165 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:41.165 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:50,167 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:50.166 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:15:59,656 sharingd[10720]: 14:15:59.656 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:03,411 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,411 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,412 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,412 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,412 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,413 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,413 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,413 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,414 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,414 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,414 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,415 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,415 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,415 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,416 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,416 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,416 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,417 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,417 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:03,417 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,167 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:08.166 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:08,420 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,420 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,421 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,421 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,421 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,422 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:08,422 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:12,872 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:16,831 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:16.830 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:23,523 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:26,272 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:26.272 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:35,704 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:35.703 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:46,389 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:46.388 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:51,069 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:51,070 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:51,070 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:51,070 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:54,861 sharingd[10720]: 14:16:54.860 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:16:58,278 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,278 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,279 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,279 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,280 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,405 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,405 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,405 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,406 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,406 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,408 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,408 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,408 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,409 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,410 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:58,410 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:16:59,369 nsurlstoraged[10711]: ERROR: shrinkDB - shrink of file system cache did not fully complete.  Result: 11
14.05.15 14:17:01,306 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,306 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,306 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,307 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,307 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,307 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,308 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,308 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,310 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,312 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,313 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,314 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,314 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,314 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,315 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,315 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,316 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,316 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,317 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,317 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,318 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,320 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,321 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,323 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:01,324 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:02,413 nsurlstoraged[10711]: ERROR: shrinkDB - shrink of file system cache did not fully complete.  Result: 11
14.05.15 14:17:03,815 sharingd[10720]: 14:17:03.814 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:17:04,319 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,319 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,320 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,320 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,321 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,321 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,321 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,322 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,322 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:04,322 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:10,505 sharingd[10720]: 14:17:10.505 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:17:11,983 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:11,983 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:11,984 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:11,984 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:11,984 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:11,985 nsurlstoraged[10711]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/user/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
14.05.15 14:17:19,494 sharingd[10720]: 14:17:19.494 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:17:23,821 sharingd[10720]: 14:17:23.821 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
14.05.15 14:18:26,623 discoveryd[72]: Basic Sockets UDS FD=3 ERROR: failed to get effective user ID, errno 0
14.05.15 14:18:27,650 WindowServer[180]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
14.05.15 14:18:28,500 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SecurityAgent.234) Path not allowed in target domain: type = uid, path = /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/XPCServices/SandboxedServiceRunner.xpc/Contents/MacOS/SandboxedServiceRunner error = 1: Operation not permitted, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SecurityAgent.xpc
14.05.15 14:18:28,500 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SecurityAgent.234) Path not allowed in target domain: type = uid, path = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechRecognitionCore.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd error = 1: Operation not permitted, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SecurityAgent.xpc
```

Do you guys have any idea on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard to pinpoint things from one crash log.

Have a look here in how to interpret kernel panics and see if you have any. If you do, log the time of each panic and list that in summary in your question (or ask a new one).

Then find the Apple Knowledge base about troubleshooting kernel panics and progress through the triage steps.

Lastly, each time it freezes, run a sysdiagnose. You can do that by pressing all five keys and then releasing them at the same time - <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

[How do you get system diagnostic files from OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/)

Basically, you'll have some research to learn how to isolate the cause, then some data collection to know how often this is happening. Once that is done, we can dig onto the logs - especially sysdiagnose while hung or looking at the pattern of kernel panics.