# Mac use Cmd-Opt-Control-Shift-, (comma) as a hotkey

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Is there a way to use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> as  hotkey?

The same modifier keys (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>) work fine with letters, but I can't seem to make it do anything when using the <kbd>,</kbd> key.

Is it a system hotkey that needs to be removed from a plist somewhere? Or is it something deeper that can't be reassigned at all?

Comment: idk what it does, but I can't assign it either [El Capitan]

Comment: Control-Option-Command-Comma (,) is a shortcut for the screen (i think) so commas are allowed it seems.

Comment: Also, `Command-,` opens the preferences for the focused app.

Answer (score 3):

Command-Option-Shift-Control-, starts a system diagnose process. I'm not really sure about the specifics, but try it and you'll get a zip archive with some information in it.

Comment: See [How do you get system diagnostic files from OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/how-do-you-get-system-diagnostic-files-from-os-x) for details.

Comment: From the link, isn't it cmd+opt+ctrl+shift with a period for starting a system diagnosis, instead of a comma?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to hotkey <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> in Spectacle and XCode by inputting <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> where <kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> are input as separate keystrokes.

In Spectacle it listed the binding as <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

In XCode it listed the binding as <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd><</kbd>.

To trigger the hotkey, you must input <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: Good find! I will note, that, when triggering the hotkey, you still you still must input `/` and `,` as separate keystrokes.