# Where Exactly are Apple Diagnostics Results Stored on Disk

Tags: finder, macos, apple-diagnostics

I know that on macOS you can access the last run Apple Diagnostics test in System Information, as seen in the image below.

[image]

You can also access reference codes in the Terminal using `system_profiler SPDiagnosticsDataType | grep "Reference Code"`.

Where on disk is this information actually stored? Or how could I use Finder to access this information? I understand there are a few other questions that are asking about software diagnostics, but I am looking specifically for hardware diagnostic results. I have checked the following directories already, and have not found the Apple Diagnostics results.

~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

~/Library/Logs

/Library/Logs

/private/var/log

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Allan, to clarify on why this question is not a duplicate, the linked question shows where to find software/macOS diagnostic logs, but I am specifically looking for Apple Diagnostics test results, which verifies only hardware.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried?:

/Private/var/tmp

### http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/29/sysdiagnose-system-diagnostic-mac/

[How do you get system diagnostic files from OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/how-do-you-get-system-diagnostic-files-from-os-x)

I usually dont just post links but there are several things in this post that you can see if they are locatable on your system. If not feel free to let us know so we can search for you.

Comment: Thanks! I checked that post, but I cannot seem to find the actual Apple Diagnostics (for hardware) results in any directory listed.

Comment: I edited my answer @Jake3231

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you updating your answer, but I'm not sure that those directories or articles contain information on Apple Diagnostics results.