# WifiDiagnostics files filling up drive even with logging disabled

Tags: wifi, catalina, logs, macos

Since upgrading to OS X Catalina, I started getting disk full notifications. After some looking, I discovered the cause is ~400 MB files in `/private/var/tmp` like this:

```
WiFiDiagnostics_2019-10-23_12.58.55.713_Mac OS X_MacBookPro15,4_19A602.tgz
```

Option-clicking on the wifi icon in the menu bar shows "Enable Wi-Fi Logging" (indicating it's disabled; if it's enabled, it shows "Disable…").

My findings so far:

- It seems to happen more frequently on certain wifi networks than others.
- It seems to happen more when Wireguard is running, and more when Wireguard is in use for a VPN. (It still happens with Wireguard quit, but not as much, it seems.)
- At one point, it was creating a new file (~400mb) every 5 minutes.
- I've tried enabling and disabling wifi logging, without luck.

I haven't been able to find anything on google. How do I stop the auto-generation of diagnostic logs?

**Update:** I've updated to 10.15.1, and also did an OS reinstall (not full disk wipe), and am still getting the log files appearing.

**Update 2, Resolution?** Short version: Somehow the command+option+control+shift+w key combo is triggering this.

Longer version: I did a full disk wipe and reinstall, then kept an eye on when this issue reappeared and installed my normal apps slowly. This file reappeared once I installed Karabiner to make my caps-lock key map to command+control+option+shift, which I use with Alfred App to make application keyboard shortcuts.

One of the shortcuts I made was command+control+option+shift+w to open iTerm. I'd noticed before that hitting this key combination made the screen flash white, but I couldn't find any information (at all, anywhere) nor any existing keyboard shortcuts indicating what that key combination would do. But sure enough, 5 minutes later, I had the log file show up.

My belief at this point is that that particular keyboard shortcut, command+option+control+shift+w, triggers something in OS X (possibly Catalina only; I don't have an older OS to test against) that starts the wifi logging.

I'm super interested to know how/why/where shift+control+option+command+w is actually being mapped. I've tried figuring out the `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file but without luck. I also tried that key combo on another Catalina install and it doesn't seem to do the same thing, so perhaps there's another app I have installed that configured that keyboard shortcut. But at this point I don't have the time to re-wipe the computer and set it up again to track it down.

Comment: It may _look_ disabled in the UI, but if it isn't really disabled, as you have found, try Enabling it, wait a minute, then Disable it. I've found, sometimes, that by forcing a setting, I call it 'retoggling', macOS sometimes re-writes a settings .plist file that may have gone wonky.

Comment: @IconDaemon No luck, unfortunately. VPN seems to exacerbate it, but it might just be because I'm on the VPN most of the time.

Comment: I've removed the VPN and profile configs, turned wifi off and on, rebooted, and I'm still getting logs ever ~5 minutes. Fills up my drive in about a day. Nothing I do seems to have any impact.

Comment: Command-Option-Shift-Control-Period (.) is indicated by this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/how-do-you-get-system-diagnostic-files-from-macos/87982#87982

Comment: @ankii Thanks! I'd actually seen that key combo trigger the behaviour as well, after my last update. Looks like that's as close to an answer as we're going to get. I used Karabiner to make those specific key chords map to "escape" instead (just so they don't trigger that behaviour).

Comment: That's some good digging! I found out all these files existed with Disk Inventory X app. My storage was filled and I donno why. This folder took up 60GB! I also installed Karabiner, and use hyper+w to maximize my window with Slate app (where hyper is shift+control+option+command). Can confirm this causes it for me as well. But having edited my .slate file I no longer use hyper+w. It still causes the debug to be taken. I just have to work around not to use that combo!

Comment: @sunapi386 I added a rule in Karabiner to make hyper+w (and hyper+>) map to "escape", because I kept hitting it out of habit or accidentally. Worth tweaking Karabiner just to make sure, if you're using the hyper key.

Comment: @brett_f I have the same issue - would you share how you set up that rule?  I've only been able to find "from the internet" as an option to create new rules in Karabiner Elements.

Comment: @Freewalker I've added my Karabiner config to an answer below. I didn't recall how I did this, but apparently you have to edit the `karabiner.json` directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Answering my own question, since others seem to be having this issue as well.)

The "hyper+w" (command+option+control+shift+w) key combo is triggering the the wifi logging. Note that "hyper+>" also seems to trigger this. I haven't been able to figure out *why* it's happening, but that's the culprit.

I've used Karabiner Elements to disable those keyboard shortcuts entirely, to prevent accidentally triggering this wifi logging. Here's the relevant section from the `karabiner.json` file to make those key combos trigger an escape instead of the wifi logging. To add these rules, go to the "Misc" tab, and do the export/import "Open config folder", then edit the `karabiner.json` to include the following two rules.

```
"rules": [
    {
        "description": "Disabling command+control+option+shift+w. This triggers wifi logging.",
        "manipulators": [
            {
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "w",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "mandatory": [
                            "command",
                            "control",
                            "option",
                            "shift"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "escape"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "description": "Disabling command+control+option+shift+>. This triggers wifi logging also.",
        "manipulators": [
            {
                "from": {
                    "key_code": ">",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "mandatory": [
                            "command",
                            "control",
                            "option",
                            "shift"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "escape"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "description": "Change caps_lock key to command+control+option+shift. (Post escape key when pressed alone)",
        "manipulators": [
            {
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "left_shift",
                        "modifiers": [
                            "left_command",
                            "left_control",
                            "left_option"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "to_if_alone": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "escape"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Beautiful, that did it.  No more screen flash + wifi logging when accidentally hitting hyper+w.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Thanks, though this is a rather unfortunate workaround of just not using these keys. I've had hyper+w a shortcut for WhatsApp for years. I'm reluctant to give up 1/26th of the letters available, so have opted for a cronjob to clear the diagnostics files every 5 minutes. Also suboptimal.

Comment: Thank you, been searching for this for a long time!

Comment: I know that "Me Too!" comments/answers are discouraged, but dang.  I feel VERY grateful right now for the time you spent figuring this out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lose the hyper+w shortcut, you can use Karabiner Elements to remap it to an unused key.  In this example I map it to F13 in `karabiner.json`:

```
{
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "description": "Change hyper+w to F13 (to avoid system binding of hyper-w which creates 500mb wifi diagnostics file in /var/tmp)",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "w",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
            "left_shift",
            "left_option",
            "left_control",
            "left_command"
          ]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "f13"
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
},
```

I intercept F13 in Hammerspoon (`~/.hammerspoon/init.lua`) to open my web browser:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "f13", function()
  window = hs.window.find("Vivaldi")
  if window then
    window:raise()
    window:focus()
  end
end)
```

(Many thanks to brett_f for figuring this out - this was driving me mad!  I couldn't figure out how those Wifi diagnostic files were being created!

I don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer, so I'm posting my answer as a slight variation)

Answer (score 1):

[This Karabiner-Elements complex modification](https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/#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) will enable brett_f's solution for both Meta-W and Meta->.

Edit: I've now published a fix for this to the [official repository of KarabinerElements complex_modification rules](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/). It's called [Disable WifiDiagnostics shortcuts (Free up Hyper-W)](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#disable_wifidiagnostics) and it uses Michael Graham's solution to remap the keyboard shortcut command+control+option+shift+, to f13 so it can still be used by other applications (I detect it in Alfred).