# Keyboard shortcut flashes my display

Tags: shortcut, keybindings, macos

If I press the keyboard shorcut  <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Shft-Ctrl-W</kbd> from any app it seems to flash my entire display.   I believe this started with Catalaina but I could be wrong.

I thought at first it was Keyboard Maestro doing it but the shortcut flashes my display even when Keyboard Maestro is not loaded.

Any ideas what  <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Shft-Ctrl-W</kbd> does and why it flashes the screen?

Comment: The same thing happens to me. It looks pretty similar to the screen flash you get in System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Audio -> Test Screen Flash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from this question:

[WifiDiagnostics files filling up drive even with logging disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373378/wifidiagnostics-files-filling-up-drive-even-with-logging-disabled#comment506330_373378)

> ... that particular keyboard shortcut, command+option+control+shift+w, triggers something in OS X (possibly Catalina only; I don't have an older OS to test against) that starts the wifi logging.

So please check your `/private/var/tmp`.

Comment: My /private/var/tmp was filled tihe WiFiDiagnostic files.   I have muscle memory for ctrl-cmd-opt-shift-W.

Answer (score 1):

The combination <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Shft-Ctrl-W</kbd> is some kind of system reserved combination, e.g. during updates/installs of the OS  <kbd>Cmd-Opt-Shft-Ctrl-W</kbd> opens up a GUI for the update process, including access to the update log. <s>So it may act as a "breaker" for the system itself.</s> As @ankii suggests, it triggers network diagnostics when booted, so the screen flash is there as to notify that the indeed diagnostics were triggered.