# Why is sysdiagnose constantly running?

Tags: macos, cpu

Every ten minutes or so sysdiagnose hogs all my CPU cores. Trying to Google for the problem leads to a lot of advice of how to run sysdiagnose as a solution to other problems. I guess it is another app running it constantly, any way to easily work out which one?

Comment: Is it bound to a shortcut like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377248/keyboard-shortcut-flashes-my-display/377261#377261

Comment:  Could be, I had used that shortcut to switch spaces (for reasons related to a Keyboard Meastro macro), I've changed it up so we will see what happens.

I'm a little suspicious of whether it is this based on the apparent semi regularity it was running at. But best lead I have so far, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bound to `Cmd-Opt-Shft-Ctrl-W` or (Q not sure which)

I was using them to power a Keyboard Maestro macro, using a different shortcut has resolved the issue.

Credit to @anki for point this out