# When using VSCode on macOS, randomly a `sysdiagnose.tar.gz` will be generated

Tags: macos, crash, visual-studio-code

I'm using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to develop TypeScript. All versions are their most up-to-date (and this was happening with 10.15.6, so it's not a 10.15.7 issue).

Randomly a Finder window will pop up at `/private/var/tmp` with a new sysdiagnose dump.

The file is called `sysdiagnose_[date stamp]_[MacBook Pro machine details].tar.gz`. When unpacked, it contains an entire folder structure full of dumps.

As such it's massively unhelpful! Which one do I need to care about?

I've checked Console.app but it also isn't very helpful unless you know what you're looking for. I do see a pile of events generated by `spindump` but they all just say `Already saw task <private> [10437] in this stackshot, ignoring second instance`. I don't see anything obvious immediately before these events.

What might be causing this, and how do I go about using these tools to figure out what it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut flashes my display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377248/keyboard-shortcut-flashes-my-display)

Comment: @anki I've noticed my screen flashing, but there's no way I'm accidentally triggering that key combination. I am using Karabiner, and Vim mode in VSCode, and have noticed the flash when I press `Caps Lock`, which I have mapped to `Esc`. I'll see if I can spot a pattern there.

Comment: It's the next morning, and I can see a `sysdiagnose` folder sitting there from 20:00 last night – when I was eating dinner. So it's definitely not me hitting the key combo. I did just press that key combo to test it, and there's no way I'm doing it accidentally.

Comment: You may be lucky at their bug tracker: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=

Answer (score 1):

Most likelely you hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> now and then which triggers system diagnostics (see [How do you get system diagnostic files from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/how-do-you-get-system-diagnostic-files-from-macos/87982#87982)) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but see my comments on my original question. This isn't it.