# Is there a system keystroke (interrupt) I can press to force a coredump on OSX?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

How do I force MacOS to dump the state of the running processes and reboot without the need to open a windows or open a command line?  My system is effectively unresponsive to non-system interrupt activities (keystrokes take minutes to process - holding down the power button works).  Is there a key sequence that can tell MacOS to snapshot state and reboot for later diagnosis?  Does MacOS possibly store a system dump somewhere after a forced system reboot?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  One question per question is best, but I’ll answer the two big ones. Feel free to link here with a follow on question if you have more after reading the restart and diagnosis links.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Here is the main list of shortcuts.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

First get a `sysdiagnose` with shift - control - command - option - period

- [How do you get system diagnostic files from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/how-do-you-get-system-diagnostic-files-from-macos)

Then choose whichever restart or shutdown option you want from Apple’s list.